# Traffic routing when accessing Firestore through Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Does accessing Firestore through Firebase cloud functions routes requests through Google internal network ?

Comment: Hi @psaw.mora please, consider accepting/upvoting my answer, in case it helped with your doubts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, request between Firestore through Cloud Functions use Google internal network to route its packages.

To provide a little bit more of context, as mentioned at [locations on Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/locations), Firebase uses GCP resources which are created as needed, this means that it also creates a VPC network as with any GCP project. As mentioned at [VPC network overview](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc), Google uses the internal network for resources in the same VPC network so in short, yes, Firebase end up using the Google internal network when communicating between functions and Firestore

Let me know if the clarified your doubts!